# how a hive table should be created when we need query based on daily data

Tags: sql, hive

i want to understand if i need to query a table and query is something like below

> Select * from table_name where date_column > sysdate-2 and date_column < sysdate;

note: my intention is to select data of each day to be specific

then how should i design my table for better results?? i think partitioning based on date will give too many partitions and lead to performance bottle neck , not sure whether bucketing works here.... plz suggest and some explanation

Comment: Partition by date.  That has been sort of a standard way of using Hive since it was first released.

Comment: then 365 days will create 365 partitions and which could let to other issues isnt it?? namenode need to maintain all the metadata for it.. plz correct me

Comment: I have added a possible solution. Please check and let me know. Query not tested.

Comment: 365 partitions is nothing.  Once you have millions of partitions then yeah, you might have to worry.  Gordon is right partition by date in YYYY-MM-DD format so that way when you move on to Oozie you can build dependencies on this dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data on a daily basis is just not enough to create a partition, you must think on creating partition based on `yyyyMM` (Year and Month). In that case, your query changes to

```
Select * from table_name where 
my_partition_col in (date_format(sysdate,'yyyyMM'), date_format(sysdate-2,'yyyyMM')) 
AND date_column > sysdate-2 and date_column < sysdate;
```

This optimizes the storage and performance requirement.

Comment: Plus :  use columnar storage (ORC, Parquet) and make sure data for each day are concentrated in as few files as possible. That will allow "skip scan" access i.e. skipping I/O on the file zones that don't match the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should partition by date.

You are correct that this will create a lot of partitions. Within Hive, each date will be a separate file, and yes, Hive will need to maintain all of that, but that's exactly what Hive is best at.

> note: my intention is to select data of each day to be specific

Since this is your intention, you'll get the best performance with daily partitions.

Other sorts of queries, running across multiple dates, may result in the performance bottleneck you're expressing concern about. But if that occurs, you could consider creating a different table to address that use case.

For your primary, current use case, daily partitions are the solution.